# Laravel 5 incorrect namespace

Tags: php, laravel-5

My app structure is this:

```
app
-- http
-- -- controllers
-- -- -- Admin
-- -- -- -- ExampleController.php
-- ExampleModel.php
```

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleController extends Controller {
```

My model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExampleModel extends Model {
```

My Error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ExampleModel' not found
```

What would be the correct namespace for the following structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do

```
use App\ExampleModel;
```

in your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

**use App\ExampleModel;**

class ExampleController extends Controller {
```